# URL error for some files,The requested document was not found on this server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi every one i have a funny problem. i want to read an URL from a database ,but it give me this error for some videos! not all of them!(the error is `The requested document was not found on this server.` )In local network it work fine and all the movies are playing!, but when i upload the site in internet, the error occurs.
any idea?
and here is the fine URL:
http://babakpirmoradi.ir/User/videos/Ostadpirmoradi2.flv
here is the url that gives error:
http://babakpirmoradi.ir/User/videos/418619301525735_21489.mp4

here is my code:
(GetUrl() pass the URL dynamically)

```
<div style="width: 650px">
<video id="example_video_1" align="center" class="video-js" controls="controls" 
       height="442" preload="auto" width="590">
<source src=<%=GetURL()%> type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'/>    
</video></div>
```

here is my url cod:

```
public string GetURL()
    {
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlconn.Open();
        sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Video FROM AddVideo where ID=@ID", sqlconn);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Request.QueryString["ID"]);
        string URL = ((string)sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar()).ToString();
        return URL;
    }
```

Comment: can you show your GetURL code ?

Comment: http://babakpirmoradi.ir/User/videos/418619301525735_21489.mp4 some file is getting downloaded. What is that

Comment: public string GetURL()
    {
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
        sqlconn.Open();
        sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Video FROM AddVideo where ID=@ID", sqlconn);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Request.QueryString["ID"]);
        string URL = ((string)sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar()).ToString();
        return URL;
    }

Comment: I put a file in that folder by copy and past(babakpirmoradi.ir/User/videos)...but it gives me the same error !!!!

Comment: you're wide open to a sql injection there, taking an unvalidated ID from the public

Comment: you mean that anybody can hack it easily??

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the video actually does not exists or we have no rights to access it:

[image: The video does not exist]

Comment: thank you for your answer... but it exist!!! I put the movie the by copy and paste in host... and i check it again.
if you check the the other URL you will see that the other is exist!